# How to find the geolocation of a private IP address?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, geolocation, ip

So, i have a node.js application running on Heroku. What i want to achieve is that when the user grants permission I'm able to geolocate that user. For this, i need IP address of that user which I was able to get via my code. The problem is that I'm unable to geolocate the user using this private IP address(It is not allowed). Are there any alternatives to achieve what I want?

Comment: Usually you use the IP of their public facing connection - you’d get this server side as the requesting IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IP geolocation is ONLY working on public IP address.

Private IP address is being used worldwide and co-existing in multiple locations at the same time. There is NO WAY you can geolocate private IP address without other unique identifier such as public IP address, MAC address or nearby base station.